# Unable to ping a remote subnet vm

Tags: networking, routes, ethernet

I have the following topology

vm 
(enp0s9 : 192.168.4.2/24)

vm1 
(enp0s9 : 192.168.4.1/24)
(enp0s10 : 192.168.3.1/24)

vm2 
(enp0s10 : 192.168.3.2/24)

I have the right l3 routing information set up on each vm and vm2

I am able to ping

vm -> vm1

and vm2->vm1

also

ping vm -> 192.168.3.1
and 
ping vm2->192.168.4.1

but I am not able to ping

vm->vm2
and vm2->vm

I am attaching screen shots for reference

[image: vm]

[image: vm1]

[image: vm2]

Answer (score 0):

Git it resolved, I forgot to check the ip forwarding on vm1

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1